# I can't organize interaction between two classes, belonging to different frames in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The two classes belong to different frames. The challenge is
to read data from the window ʻent_data`class a parent of`ForLeftFrame `in a descendant class of` ForRightFrameChild`.
When calling the parent class, a message appears in the console:
"name 'left_frame' is not defined". Can't figure out why?
Everything works in one frame. Please help me figure it out.
The code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

#-----------
class ForLeftFrame():
    def __init__(self, left_frame):
        self.left_frame = left_frame

        self.ent_data = tk.Entry(left_frame, width=8, bg='#3de',
            fg='#dff')
        self.ent_data.grid(column=0, row=1)

#-----------
class ForRightFrameChild(ForLeftFrame):
    def __init__(self, right_frame):
        self.right_frame = right_frame

        super().__init__(self, left_frame)
        self.left_frame = left_frame

        self.transf_button = tk.Button(right_frame, text="Transfer to...",
            bg='#489', fg='#dff', command=self.transferTo)
        self.transf_button.grid(column=0, row=1)

    def transferTo(self):
        self.ent_data_st = self.ent_data.get()
        print('Transfer to...', self.ent_data_st)

#-----------
class Application(tk.Frame):
    """Главный класс приложения"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()

        left_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg='tan', relief='groove', bd=3)
        left_frame.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)
        righr_frame = tk.Frame(master, bg='aqua', relief='groove', bd=3)
        righr_frame.pack(side='right', fill='both', expand=1)

        self.for_left_frame = ForLeftFrame(left_frame)
        self.for_right_frame_child = ForRightFrameChild(righr_frame)

#-----------------------------
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive this you need to have references and that is exactly what the error suggests.

So what I did in the code below is first to write your application as a subclass of `tk.Tk()` so the root parameter or you window is now your own class to modify, also it becomes the controller/director in this ensemble.

Also I created your frames as a subclass of frames, how you did it first with only the application class.

Now, all the *magic* is in this line and I will explain what happens here for a better understanding.

```
self.master.left_frame.ent_data.get()
```

So **self** *reference* to the *instance of the class* which we had bound to `self.right_frame` in our class named Application.

The class **Application is** also the **master** of *self/right_frame*.
The Application **has** the **attribute** **left_frame** which we did by `self.left_frame` in the Application class.
self.left_frame was bound to a reference of an instance from the class `LeftFrame` were we have defined the attribute `ent_data` which is an tk.Entry that has the method get.

I know it seems confusing in the beginning and you may need to read this text more then onnce, but this is how it works. It is more or less a straight way to go.

```
import tkinter as tk

#-----------
class LeftFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.ent_data = tk.Entry(self, width=8, bg='#3de',fg='#dff')
        self.ent_data.grid(column=0, row=1)

#-----------
class RightFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)

        self.transf_button = tk.Button(self, text="Transfer to...",
                                       bg='#489', fg='#dff',
                                       command=self.transferTo)
        self.transf_button.grid(column=0, row=1)

    def transferTo(self):
        self.ent_data_st = self.master.left_frame.ent_data.get()
        print('Transfer to...', self.ent_data_st)

#-----------
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.left_frame = LeftFrame(self)
        self.right_frame = RightFrame(self)

        self.left_frame.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=1)
        self.right_frame.pack(side='right', fill='both', expand=1)


#-----------------------------
app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

EDIT:

```
import tkinter as tk

#-----------
class LeftFrame(object):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.f = frame
        self.ent_data = tk.Entry(self.f, width=8, bg='#3de',fg='#dff')
        self.ent_data.grid(column=0, row=1)

#-----------
class RightFrame(object):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.f = frame
        self.transf_button = tk.Button(self.f, text="Transfer to...",
                                       bg='#489', fg='#dff',
                                       command=self.transferTo)
        self.transf_button.grid(column=0, row=1)

    def transferTo(self):
        self.ent_data_st = self.f.master.for_left_frame.ent_data.get()
        print('Transfer to...', self.ent_data_st)

#-----------
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame2 = tk.Frame(self)

        self.for_left_frame = LeftFrame(frame1)
        self.for_right_frame = RightFrame(frame2)

        frame1.pack()
        frame2.pack()


#-----------------------------
app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. He helped me a lot. But the question still remained. In other words, I can't create non-tkinter related classes and then bind them to different frames without changes inside these classes? The idea was that in some Python computational module, some actions are performed. And then the results are output to tkinter. I would be grateful for your answer.

Comment: the syntax is nearly the same. Updated.