# "Exception has occurred: AttributeError type object 'Tk' has no attribute 'tk'" issue with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been searching all day for an answer to this question and I am stumped. I am making a program with 7 buttons and 2 input fields. I have an `__init__` defined and I have the dependencies on the code above this defined. No problems with that but problems with the input and ending script.

```
class root(tk.Tk):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    frame = tk.Frame()
    button = tk.Button(frame,
                text = "Make New File",
                command=self.answer1)
    button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    button2 = tk.Button(frame, 
                text = "Edit File", 
                command = self.answer2)
    button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    button3 = tk.Button(frame, 
                text = "Append Data", 
                command = self.answer3)
    button3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    button4 = tk.Button(frame, 
                text = "Read File", 
                command = self.answer4)
    button4.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    button5 = tk.Button(frame, 
                text = "Delete File", 
                command = self.answer5)
    button5.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    buttonquit = tk.Button(frame, 
            text="QUIT", 
            fg="red",
            command=quit)
    buttonquit.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    frame = tk.Frame()
    self.L1 = tk.Label(root, text="File Name")
    self.L1.pack( side = tk.LEFT)
    self.E1 = tk.Entry(root, bd =5)
    self.E1.pack(side = tk.RIGHT)
    L2 = tk.Label(root, text="Text to Edit")
    L2.pack( side = tk.LEFT)
    self.E2 = tk.Entry(root, bd =5)
    self.E2.pack(side = tk.RIGHT)
    title = self.E1.get()
    text = self.E2.get()
    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    root.title("Catalog 2020")
john = root()
john.mainloop()
```

And here's the error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
type object 'Tk' has no attribute 'tk'
  File "C:\Users\25gbrickner\Desktop\catalogcode\catalog2020-release2.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.L1 = tk.Label(root, text="File Name")
  File "C:\Users\25gbrickner\Desktop\catalogcode\catalog2020-release2.py", line 115, in <module>
    john = root()
```

I've been searching for a while and I don't understand the issue. I did define the commands in the large code, but I whittled it down.

Comment: What do you think `james = tk.Tk` is doing?

Comment: what does this class do ? why there is two times the `tk.Tk` in your code?

Comment: I'm a beginner and it seemed to solve a problem that I had. I was told to add the class and the def for tkinter but I dont know if that is the correct solution.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be '''tk.Tk() ''' and not '''tk. Tk'''

Comment: I have no idea what this code is supposed to be but it seems wrong to me, also that the positional argument `master` is set to root instead of `self`. You may take a look at this code here as a reference. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64293547/13629335

Comment: why did you edit the question and add a second `__init__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in your code. First, you are improperly inheriting from `tk.Tk` by neglecting to call the `__init__` of the superclass.

You need to add this to the top of your `__init__`:

```
super().__init__()
```

Second, in your code `root` is a class, but you're trying to use it as the parent of other widgets. In this specific case, if you want a widget to go in the root window you need to use `self`:

```
self.L1 = tk.Label(self, text="File Name")
self.E1 = tk.Entry(self, bd =5)
L2 = tk.Label(self, text="Text to Edit")
self.E2 = tk.Entry(self, bd =5)
frame = tk.Frame(self)
```

Also, you need to name the class `Root`, as the convention in python is to capitalize class names.

Similarly, you have a problem when trying to set the title. You need to call `self.title` rather than `root.title`:

```
self.title("Catalog 2020")
```

Finally, you need to remove `james = tk.Tk`. It does nothing, and you never use `james`. You also need to remove `frame = tk.Frame()` because it causes you to create two root windows. There should always only ever be one. Plus, you never use this `frame` instance.

---

Unrelated to the question being asked, you're calling `self.E1.get()` and `self.E2.get()` about a millisecond after creating the entry widget, well before the user even sees the entry widget.

You need to wait to call these methods until after the user has entered data and performed some sort of action such as clicking a button or pressing the return key, or something like that.

Comment: Ok that worked but now my buttons have disappeared, I am not sure why

Comment: @CatalogCrypto: the code you posted doesn't have any buttons.

Comment: Should I edit it to include them because I did write them.

Comment: @CatalogCrypto: no, because that's not relevant to the question.

Comment: Ok, I'll write a new question when I can, thank you

Comment: @CatalogCrypto first you had defined two `init` methods and second you never placed or packed your frame in the code. Also even a frame needs a master and the root window will it be by default.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm not quite sure as I'm new to coding and am adding UI to a command line script.

Comment: @CatalogCrypto If your new to coding, i recommend not using classes and OOP with tkinter yet.

Comment: Also, I'm quite sure I packed the frame but I could be wrong.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it, I moved the pack argument to the top of the script

Comment: @CatalogCrypto please take a look at this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235